# Macro to find and delete column based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have two sheets in an Excel workbook. I would like a VBA code to search for the content of cell J19 in Sheet2 and delete the column with the matching cell in Sheet1. I have been searching all around Google to look for some VBA codes, but I haven't found anything yet that works.

Does anybody here know how to do this? I have zero experience in VBA.

Comment: Welcome to S.O! Have you tried anything? If so, please, provide the code, take a look to the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Friendly reminder: StackOverflow is not a "we code for you" service provider. [Introduction to VBA](https://blog.udemy.com/excel-macros-tutorial/) Hint: You are never going to find the solution for your specific problem, break it in little pieces, first ["Find a word excel vba"](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/find-method.htm) then tailor it to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this code to perform such a task.

```
Sub FindMatchAndThenDeleteColumn()

    FindContent = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("J19")

    For Each Cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Cells
        If Cell.Value = FindContent Then Columns(Cell.Column).Delete
    Next

End Sub
```

Put the code above in your [workbook's module](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/run-code-from-a-module.html). Note that `FindContent` and `Cell` are randomly chosen here, you can use any names. I use

```
   For Each Cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Cells
```

to loop through every cell that is in use in **Sheet1**. It will check everything in the range from cell A1 to the last cell with data (the bottom right-most cell). If the content of cell J19 is a text, you can declare the variable `FindContent` as a `String` type, i.e. `Dim FindContent As String`. If it's a number, you can declare it as a `Long` type or a `Single` type or any number type that fits the content. Here I don't declare it which means it defaulting to a `Variant` type. And since you're a beginner in VBA, you may learn it from [Excel Easy](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples.html). Hope this helps.